# How can I expert searching/sorting/filtering in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am struggling with complex filtering data such as nested object to nested array . I am looking for resources where can I learn how to improve filtering/searching/sorting in javascript.

For example, [{key:"1"}] to ["1"] or something else that can be very complex .

Comment: Resource requests are off-topic on StackOverflow. It's better to ask a specific question about a specific problem you're facing.

Answer (score 0):

I usually refer to MDN's docs, as they provide detailed explanations of how to use functions as well as examples. You can find the docs for [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) here, but they also have docs on tons of other things. This will show you how to use `.filter`, `.find`, `.sort`, among other things as you had requested.

If you're specifically wondering about the example you posted, you can use `.map` to accomplish that:

```js
const original = [{ key: "1" }, { key: "2" }];
const mapped = original.map(i => i.key);
console.log(mapped); // ["1", "2"]
```